# I don't know why Room is not inserting all the data in tables 1 - N

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Please someone help me! I'm doing a small project and I have this function:

```
private fun getRoutePoints(routeId: String) {
        val dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/routes/$routeId")
        val listOfPoints: MutableList<PointOfInterest> = mutableListOf()
        dbReference.child("pointsOfInterest").get().addOnSuccessListener { pointsArray ->
            pointsArray.children.forEach { point ->
                val dataMap = point.value as Map<*, *>
                val routeIdToInsert = routeId.toInt()
                val id = point.key!!.toInt()
                val pointOfInterest = PointOfInterest(
                    id = id,
                    title = dataMap["title"].toString(),
                    description = dataMap["description"].toString(),
                    latitude = dataMap["latitude"].toString().toDouble(),
                    longitude = dataMap["longitude"].toString().toDouble(),
                    imageUrl = dataMap["imageUrl"].toString(),
                    routeId = routeIdToInsert
                )
                listOfPoints.add(id, pointOfInterest)
                if (pointsArray.children.count() == listOfPoints.size) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        AppDatabase.getInstance(application).routeDao.insertRoutePoints(listOfPoints)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It appears when the second insertion has been done, the execution returns to the for each again, like if all children are not being looped

> My DAO class

```
>     @Dao interface RouteDao {
>     @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
>     suspend fun insertRoute(route: Route)
> 
>     @Query("SELECT * FROM routes_tbl")
>     fun getAllRoutes(): List<Route>
> 
>  
> 
>    @Transaction
>     @Insert
>     fun insertRoutePoints(points: List<PointOfInterest>) }
```

My entities:
My Route Entity:

```
> @Entity(tableName = "routes_tbl") data class Route(
>     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "historic_period") val historicPeriod: String,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") val imageUrl: String )
```

My PointOfInterest entity:

```
>     @Entity(tableName = "points_tbl", foreignKeys = [
>          ForeignKey(
>             entity = Route::class,
>             parentColumns = ["id"],
>             childColumns = ["route_id"],
>             onDelete = CASCADE,
>             onUpdate = CASCADE
>         )]) data class PointOfInterest(
>         @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int,
>         @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
>         @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String,
>         @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude") val latitude: Double,
> 
>  @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude") val longitude: Double,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") val imageUrl: String,
>     @ColumnInfo(name = "route_id") val routeId: Int )
```

The entity with the relation  1-N:

```
data class RouteWithPointsOfInterest(
    @Embedded val route: Route,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "route_id"
    ) val pointsOfInterest: List<PointOfInterest>
)
```

You can clone the project here

https://github.com/albertbuigues/Touristics

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are describing what happens if when building an array you use that array rather than using the array when it has finally been built.

That is on the first iteration the single PointOfInterest is added. However, on the second iteration, the array has 2 elements (the first and another), when you try to insert the list of two PointsOfInterest, the first insert has an issue as an attempt is being made to insert a **duplicate**.

- You could get around this by using `@Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)`, the conflict (the attempt to an an already existing id) will be ignored.

However, you should be waiting until the array ListOfPoints, has been built and then insert all at once. so :-

```
private fun getRoutePoints(routeId: String) {
    val dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/routes/$routeId")
    val listOfPoints: MutableList<PointOfInterest> = mutableListOf()
    dbReference.child("pointsOfInterest").get().addOnSuccessListener { pointsArray ->
        pointsArray.children.forEach { point ->
            val dataMap = point.value as Map<*, *>
            val routeIdToInsert = routeId.toInt()
            val id = point.key!!.toInt()
            val pointOfInterest = PointOfInterest(
                id = id,
                title = dataMap["title"].toString(),
                description = dataMap["description"].toString(),
                latitude = dataMap["latitude"].toString().toDouble(),
                longitude = dataMap["longitude"].toString().toDouble(),
                imageUrl = dataMap["imageUrl"].toString(),
                routeId = routeIdToInsert
            )
            listOfPoints.add(id, pointOfInterest)
            /* MOVED
            if (pointsArray.children.count() == listOfPoints.size) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    AppDatabase.getInstance(application).routeDao.insertRoutePoints(listOfPoints)
                }
            }
             */
        }
        if (listOfPoints.size > 0 ) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                AppDatabase.getInstance(application).routeDao.insertRoutePoints(listOfPoints)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the `insertRoutePoints` Dao were changed to `fun insertRoutePoints(points: List<PointOfInterest>): Array<Long>` then array returned will have the id of the respective inserted row in the respective element of the array. If the value is -1, rather than a positive value, then it was not inserted. So you have a means of determining how many were actually inserted.

Processing the entire array/list also means that all the inserts would be done in a single transaction. Rather than many individual transactions. The is no need to use @Transaction for an @Insert, it will be a single transaction.

Comment: It did not work, it only writes the ones with the route_id (foreign_key) = 0, but not the ones with route_id = 1. I will continue to try